# WebBrowser call Javascript function in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webbrowser-control

I have a C# WinForm application with a WebBrowser control, which loads an ASP.NET page. What I'm trying to accomplish is to be able to call a JavaScript function from the C# application to the ASP.NET application.

The Javascript function is declared in the Masterpage as following:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function HelloWorld(myString)
{
    alert('C# says ' + myString);
}
</script>
```

I'm testing the function from the .aspx.cs (code-behind) to see if I can reach it:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "HelloWorld",     
"HelloWorld('Bummer, this was from ASP.NET :(');", true);
```

This works, and the message is printed out. I remove this line from the code-behind file.

In my C# application I do the following:

```
private void CallHelloWorld(WebBrowser _webBrowser, string _sMessage)
{
    object[] _objects = {_sMessage};
    _webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("HelloWorld",_objects);
}
```

There is no response from the ASP.NET application. I've also tried printing out the `_webBrowser.DocumentText` (to check the page source code), but there are no JavaScript functions present here (just some declarations for PlaceHolders etc).

Comment: Check this http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/127356/Calling-JavaScript-function-from-WinForms-and-vice

Comment: how do you ensure the document has loaded before calling the function.

Comment: I'll checke your URL, thanks.

The comment about wheter or not the document is loaded is not relevant, as I have not provided code stating I'm having such issues.

Comment: malkam: that did not solve my issue regarding communication to JavaScript to an ASP.NET application. 
I am using ObjectForScripting, and this works fine on a HTML page.

Comment: I could not edit the comment, so I'm posting the updated version of it:

malkam: that did not solve my issue regarding the communication to a JavaScript function in an ASP.NET application. 
I am using ObjectForScripting, and this works fine on a HTML page. If you look at my example I do the same thing using DocumentInvokeScript with an object.

Comment: *I've also tried printing out the _webBrowser.DocumentText (to check the page source code), but there are no JavaScript functions* - obviously, you should solve this one first. Cleary, it's a problem with you server-side code which doesn't generate correct `<script>` tags.